# How to mix-in a construction-time code to a class with a trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, traits

I want all the classes extending the trait to store their creation time (as a `org.joda.time.DateTime` instance). The trait defines `def dt : DateTime` as a getter. Can I also define the code to take the timestamp (which is intended to run at construction time) in the trait?

UPDATE: I think I've came to an idea how to implement the particular task without dealing with constructors (just define `dt` as a val and set it to a new DateTime, maybe this is going to work), but the question in the title is still interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add constructors through traits.

Comment: but traits can define initialisation code, specifically val initialiasers. You can get some very strange errors due to construction initialisation order if you try and use these techniques to simulate paramaterised construction though, and it is definitely not recommended to try.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the implementation of the `def currentTime` to result in an `org.joda.time.DateTime` instance and mix the trait into any class.

```
trait Timestamp {
  private def currentTime = {
    import java.util.Calendar._

    val calendar = getInstance

    def hours = calendar.get(HOUR_OF_DAY)
    def minutes = calendar.get(MINUTE)
    def seconds = calendar.get(SECOND)
    def milliseconds = calendar.get(MILLISECOND)

    hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds
  }

  final val creationTime = currentTime
}
```

Comment: I've done alike already, as I've mentioned in the question update. But why all that code: a def and a final (why final?) val? I've just done that as `val creationTime = new DateTime()` and it seems working. The application makes heavy use of Scala actors by the way.

Comment: `final` to prevent `creationTime` being overriden (just in case) and the extra def just to make the code look a bit cleaner...